# Windows 7 - Ubuntu VM .VDI file disappeared

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I'm on a Windows 7 laptop and I have two Ubuntu VMs that I've been running under VirtualBox. The first is a 64 bit version of Ubuntu that I don't use, the second is the 32 bit that I do use. Unfortunately, the 32 bit .VDI file has *disappeared*.

You read that correctly, and no I did not accidentally delete it, recycle it, or touch in any way, shape, or form. I booted up my laptop this morning and the file was not there. I ran WinDirStat to list my large files - nothing. As you can see, the 64-bit version is still there, and a few supporting files are still present from my 32-bit version, but not the .VDI.

I have one other possibility but am unsure how to proceeed - occasionally my laptop will go into hibernate mode, and I'm curious if there's a possibility that it is somehow stuck in hiberfil.sys (which is currently clocking in around 4.5GB).

Anybody have any experience with a similar situation that they could share?

[image: WinDirStat capture]

Comment: Have you checked for disk corruption?

Comment: No - what would be the best way to check for this? I'm not a power Windows user so I don't know all the best tools. I'm forced to use it by my company, so I VM Ubuntu.

Comment: Computer -> Right-Click the hard drive that the VDI normally resides on -> Properties -> Tools -> Error-checking (make sure "Automatically fix file system errors" and "Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors" are checked). If it's your main hard drive, it will probably say you will need to schedule the disk check; if so, click ok, and reboot to start checking. It may take a while to check a large disk.

Comment: I've been running Ubuntu VMs on a Windows 7 machine for quite a while and I've never had an instance of them just vanishing.

Comment: Me too - I've had Ubuntu VMs running for several years now. First time its ever happened.